# How to remove blurriness from an image using opencv (python/c++)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, blur

I am using `opencv` to detect person in live video feed. I need to save the image of the person detected. But here the person is not standing and is keeps moving due to which when I am about to save the image, it is saved in very blurry format, just like below image:

As you can see the image is not very clear and has a lot of blurriness into it. Face is also not clear. Is there anyway we can remove the blurriness from image. Thanks

Comment: Reduce the exposure time. No amount of deconvolution is going to make the face better recognizable.

Answer (score 14):

You can try sharpening the image using [`cv2.filter2D()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) and a generic sharpening kernel

Here are other [sharpening kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) you can experiment with

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sharpen_kernel)

cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on how you came up with the filter `[[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]]`? The wiki article you have shared has a different filter. I tried implementing the `unsharp masking` filter (as shown in the article) but I am not getting the expected results

Comment: This is just another sharpening filter in addition to the one on the wiki.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @nathancy you can try with morhological based operations, this works in all the cases but it requires filter dimension tuning according to image shape, noise level and it also leads to drop in image quality.

Recently, Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN) has also got attention for regenrating the images and seems to be promising in image quality enhancement.

This article(https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/deblur-photos-using-generic-pix2pix-6f8774f9701e) has described a GAN based (based on pixtopix model) solution for image deblurring, this may work for your case too.